# Playwright locator fails when wrapping the page object

Tags: playwright

I'm having a weird error in Playwright that I don't understand.

I click a cancel button like this:

```
await page.locator('text=Cancel >> button').click();
```

However, when I add this exact code to my page wrapper I made based on the [Page Object Model](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-pom) docs:

```
import { Page } from 'playwright/test';

class MyPage extends Page {
  async clickCancelButton(): Promise<void> {
    await this.page.locator('text=Cancel >> button').click();
  }
}
```

Then it fails to find the button:

```
test('Click the cancel button', async ({ page }, workerInfo) => {

  const myPage = new MyPage(page);
  await myPage.goToPageWithCancelButton();
  await myPage.clickCancelButton();
```

I added many other methods to my class and they work as expected, so I don't understand what is going on here.  It's just "wait for the selector and click".

Why does it work when I call it directly but fail when it's inside my page wrapper?

**Second try: do not extend Page**

Based on the comment by @hardkoded, I stopped extending Page:

```
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';

class MyPage {
  public readonly page: Page;

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async clickCancelButton(): Promise<void> {
    await this.page.locator('text=Cancel >> button').click();
  }
}
```

However, I get the same error as described above.

Comment: I think that your issue is that you are extending the playwright page instead of `import {Page} from '@playwright/test'`

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks, I rewrote my code to not extend Page (and updated the question), but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: you are using `this.page` is not clear where `page` is coming from. I don't see a constructor expecting that value.

Comment: @hardkoded My mistake, I didn't paste in the constructor.  Updated.    `const myPage = new MyPage(page);
  await myPage.goToPageWithCancelButton();` This is the sequence that fails; but if I run the code from `goToPageWithCancelButton()` directly (`await this.page.locator('text=Cancel >> button').click();`) then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, this error was caused by using `await myPage.clickCancelButton;` in a couple places instead of
`await myPage.clickCancelButton();`

Unfortunately, ESLint, TypeScript, and friends did not point out this stupid mistake on my part.